# Unable to install any Ruby with RVM on MacOS 10.14.2 Mojave: Error running '__rvm_make -j4'

Tags: ruby, xcode, rvm, macos-mojave

After upgrading MacOS to 10.14.2 Mojave, I'm not able to install any Ruby Version with RVM anymore. It always gives an error like this:

```
$rvm install 2.5.3
ruby-2.5.3 - #removing src/ruby-2.5.3..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.14/x86_64/ruby-2.5.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/jdinse/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.5.3 - #downloading ruby-2.5.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.5.3 - #extracting ruby-2.5.3 to /Users/jdinse/.rvm/src/ruby-2.5.3.....
ruby-2.5.3 - #configuring....................................................................
ruby-2.5.3 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.5.3 - #compiling....................
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/jdinse/.rvm/log/1547136259_ruby-2.5.3/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Looking into `make.log`, the only errors are like this:

```
making srcs under enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
generating transdb.h
linking static-library libruby.2.5.3-static.a
libtool: object: dln.o malformed object (unknown load command 1)
libtool: object: localeinit.o malformed object (unknown load command 1)
libtool: object: loadpath.o malformed object (unknown load command 1)
libtool: object: array.o malformed object (unknown load command 1)
libtool: object: bignum.o malformed object (unknown load command 1)
libtool: object: class.o malformed object (unknown load command 1)
...
```

What I've tried so far:

- reinstalled RVM
- trying previous RVM 1.29.6 or master branch
- reinstalled Homebrew
- reinstalled XCode
- reinstalled Command Line Tools
- installed gcc,  gcc@7 or gcc@8 with homebrew, or uninstalled all of them
- installed openssl or openssl@1.1, or uninstalled all of them

Nothing of this nor any other tips of similar questions helped.

Any ideas? Or any idea what caused the error `libtool: object: dln.o malformed object (unknown load command 1)` and how to fix it?

Comment: any luck resolving this issue? I'm experiencing the exact same issue and I'm stumped.

Comment: I had no luck yet :( I'm thinking about switching to rbenv instead.

Comment: I was able to figure this out, i'll answer below :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well.  In my case it was due to MacPorts being outdated after I upgraded to (MacOS) Mojave.

I followed the steps listed on MacPorts' migration guide here:
https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration

Closed and reopened Terminal (just b/c)

ran `rvm install ruby` and got `Install of ruby-2.6.0 - #complete`, hooray!

Comment: Bingo!!! After the step of unistalling MacPorts I tried to install Ruby via RVM again and it worked.
BTW, while unstalling all old Macports packages, I have noticed that `boost` were uninstalled as well.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have multiple versions of boost installed? I took the following steps to fix this (although I was using rbenv).

First I removed my xcode lib:
`rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Then I reinstalled it:
`xcode-select --install`

Then I ran `brew ls` and noticed I had two versions of boost. `boost` and `boost@1.6.0`. I removed `boost@1.6.0` and `boost` and reinstalled `boost` and made sure it was linked via `brew link boost`.

Seemed to work after that.

Comment: I did that and removed my brew installation. Reinstalled brew BUT didn't install anything. Did `rvm install ruby-2.6.0` then let rvm install the dependencies `Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, coreutils, libyaml, readline, libksba, openssl@1.1`...

Comment: I have the same problem as Jay Dinse. I did not have boost installed but still I have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to fix it by completely removing (a very old version of) MacPorts. Everything else kept giving me the same issues.

Hope this works for you as well. It took me more than a day to find a hint that lead me to this point.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by :

```
brew install rbenv
rbenv install 2.7.4 #repalce 2.7.4 with the version you want
rbenv global 2.7.4
```

Tried downloading it from rvm but nothing was working